# ios using release in an async block

Tags: ios, release, dispatch-async

I have an IOS project (ARC disabled) which has several view controllers. One particular controller initialises a member object of type MyClass, however when the view controller is dismissed, I'm calling a cleanup method for the object which uses a thread (using dispatch-async) to make some time consuming operations and then when these operations are done im executing a [self release] on the main queue for the object. Is this a good practise, will it cause any errors? Below is a similar example to what im doing:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    myObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear
{
    [myObj cleanup];
}

@end

//myClass
@implementation MyClass

- (void)cleanup()
{
   dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create ("MyClassDeallocQueue", NULL);
   dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        //time consuming operations        

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self release];
        });
   });

}

@end
```

Comment: I don't do manual reference counting, but won't the block have a reference to your object? So you could call the cleanup function and then immediately release it from inside your controller. `[self release]` just seems wrong to me...

Comment: You've probably heard this before, but ARC is great.  It works so much better than manual counting.  It only took a few hours to convert our big apps over to it.

Comment: Pulz1103, i can't call the release immediately, this object needs to cleanup before it can be released

Comment: HalR, i know but in my case i need to disable ARC.

Comment: I think the bigger problem is why you need to disable ARC. And your current call is strange because in using `self` you are creating an retain. Try calling it on an __unsafe_unretained pointer to self instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good practise, will it cause any errors?

Currently, your code has an unbalanced retain/release. That is definitely an error (over release).

"Is it good practice?"  - well, I don't know what you are trying to accomplish. But if your goal is to keep `self` alive, until after the block is executed, it is already accomplished purely through the fact that `self` will be captured. So, strictly a `release` is not needed.

However, if you NOT explicitly release `self` on the main thread, you introduce a subtle bug:  it might happen that the block has the *last* reference to `self`, and since it may execute on some arbitrary thread, it will release `self` on this non-main thread. And this is forbidden: UIKit methods (including dealloc) MUST be called on the main thread!

Thus, it might make sense:

```
   [self retain];
   dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        // time consuming operation, which captures `self`        
        [self doSomething];
        ...
        // ensure that `dealloc` will be executed on the main thread, if 
        // last reference is held by the block:
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self release];
        });
   });
```

or shorter:

```
   dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        // time consuming operation, which captures `self`        
        [self doSomething];
        ...
        // ensure that `dealloc` will be executed on the main thread, if 
        // last reference is held by the block:
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self self];
        });
   });
```

**Edit:**

It's an interesting question, whether the "short" version is actually tread-safe or has a race:

Suppose, `self` will be released in the block executed on *myQueue*, as the effect of capturing `self` *before* it will be *retained* in the same bock as an effect of capturing `self` for the block executed on the main queue. Then, we have an issue. Comments appreciated.